# How to route between Angular projects?

Tags: angular, routes

I created multiple projects in my Angular project by `ng generate application`. All of them work as a separate standalone application that I can serve by `ng serve` but they use the same navbar component (each has it's own instance of the same navbar). I'd like to move between the projects by using this navbar. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Simply, you can't. Angular 7 is not architected in a way that allows one to communicate accross unique instances of an app. You could hack together a websocket listener and build an event based system of triggers and handlers, but you would be doing 10x the work to do something that, without Angular, is pretty easy. May I ask why you want to run more than one instance of the app (or variations thereof) concurrently?

Comment: These are not variations but different apps, with different functionalities. Previously, they were running in AngularJS and routing could link between them. Now, because of migration to Angular 7, I have bunch of hybrid apps, where I bootstrap the old AngularJS apps inside the Angular7 wrappers (each one has own project). The last step would be to make them communicate (it doesn't have to be in the runtime, could work so after ng building each project).

Comment: Simply href to the specific url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your application are not secured application

> For example you have 2 application running on port as follow: 
> 1)
>   http://localhost:4200 
> 2) http://localhost:4000

Now your navbar should look like this

```
   <ul class="navbar">
          <li><a href="http://localhost:4200">Application 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://localhost:4000">Application 2</a></li> 
      </ul>
```